How to linearize the following logical constraints?
I am having trouble linearizing the following logical constraints.
$x,y,z$ are non negative continuous variables such that $x=y+z$, and $A$ is a positive parameter. I would like to linearize
$$
y=
\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        x & \mbox{if  } x \le A \\
        A & \mbox{otherwise}
    \end{array}
\right.
$$
and
$$
z=
\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        0 & \mbox{if  } x \le A \\
        x-A & \mbox{otherwise}
    \end{array}
\right.
$$

Assume $0 \le x \le U$ for some constant $U$.  Introduce binary decision variable $\delta$ and impose $x=y+z$ and indicator constraints:
\begin{align}
\delta=0 &\implies (0 \le x \le A \land y = x) \tag1\label1\\
\delta=1 &\implies (A \le x \le U \land y = A) \tag2\label2
\end{align}
You can linearize \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} as follows:
\begin{align}
A \delta \le x &\le A(1-\delta)+ U \delta \\
(A - U) \delta \le y - x &\le 0 \\
A \delta \le y &\le A
\end{align}

Note that you can express the desired relationship as $y=\min(x,A)$.  If you instead wanted to enforce only $y\le\min(x,A)$, you would omit $\delta$ and just impose
\begin{align}
y &\le x \\
y &\le A
\end{align}

Is $A\delta \le x \le A(1-\delta) + U \delta$ necessary? It seems that $(1)$ and $(2)$ are satisfied without this constraint.

@Kuifje Those constraints on $x$ are valid but implied by the others and hence can be omitted. For example, $A\delta\le y$ and $y\le x$, so $A\delta \le x$.
